# Combining multiple Bluebird promises into a single promise object

Tags: javascript

I'm using the [BluebirdJS](http://bluebirdjs.com) promise library.

I have a method called getOrder which returns back an orders details based on a PO number in a form of a promise.

```
var poNumber = '12345';
return getOrder(poNumber).then(function (order) {
   console.log(order.poNumber, order.items[0].sku);
   return order;
});
```

However I now need to call this method in a loop and combine the details about the order into a single object.

What I have ATM is this:

```
var poNumbers = ['12345', '67890'];
return Promise.each(poNumbers, function (poNumber) {
   return Promise.try(function () {
      return getOrder(poNumber).then(function (order) {
          console.log(order.poNumber, order.items[0].sku);
          return order;
      });
   });
}).then(function (combinedOrder) {
   console.log(combinedOrder);
});
```

But I'm unsure how to combine the details of each order into a single object and return that object as a promise instead?

The project also uses lodash and I tried using [_.difference](https://lodash.com/docs#difference) to maybe grab the difference and make up a combined order object but I was again unsure how to get it working.

What's the best way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `Promise.all` instead of `Promise.each`:

Quoting from the [docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html):

> Given an Iterable(arrays are Iterable), or a promise of an Iterable,
>   which produces promises (or a mix of promises and values), iterate
>   over all the values in the Iterable into an array and return a promise
>   that is fulfilled when all the items in the array are fulfilled. The
>   promise's fulfillment value is an array with fulfillment values at
>   respective positions to the original array. If any promise in the
>   array rejects, the returned promise is rejected with the rejection
>   reason.